# How do I pass a list of strings to an external command in Python?

Tags: python, openbsd

I am writing a Python program that will download a list of bad IP addresses and add/remove those from a table in OpenBSD pf.  The program downloads the list, formats them (as IP address objects), and passes them to the `pfctl` command.  Right now I have it working as a loop that calls `pfctl` once for each string thusly:

```
for item in addedlist:
    subprocess.run(['pfctl', '-t', const.PF_LISTNAME, '-T', 'add',\
    str(item)], check=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

for item in deletedlist:
    subprocess.run(['pfctl', '-t', const.PF_LISTNAME, '-T', 'delete',\
    str(item)], check=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

where:

`addedlist` and `deletedlist` are the formatted lists of IP address objects to be added and removed, respectively.

I would like to run the `pfctl` command only once for each list and pass `addedlist` and `deletedlist` to the command in one shot since the lists (*cough*IPv6*cough*) can be quite lengthy.  When I try to do it, though, Python complains about not expecting a list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to pass in the list?

Comment: Discarding standard error seems like a dubious practice.

Comment: @tripleee, fair question.  The command was spitting out a line of output for each of the 100,000 or so items.  When I get it working I will take that out and capture the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate the `item`s to the argument list, not nest the `items` lists in it.

We'll also use a list comprehension to call `str` on the items.

```
subprocess.run(
    ["pfctl", "-t", const.PF_LISTNAME, "-T", "add"]
    + [str(item) for item in addedlist],
    check=True,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
subprocess.run(
    ["pfctl", "-t", const.PF_LISTNAME, "-T", "delete"]
    + [str(item) for item in deletedlist],
    check=True,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
```